# How do I convert a decimal to a string without replacing decimals?

Tags: c#

I have an object, `CellData`, that is equal to `-0.000009482102880653542`.

I want to display as is when exporting it as a `.csv` file.  To do that I have to convert the object to a string.

```
output = CellData.ToString();
output = string.Format("{0}", CellData);
```

The above two cases result in `output` being `-9.48210288065354E-06`.  I would like it to return  `output` as `-0.0000094821028806535423` (with decimals).

Is there anyway I can get this working?

Comment: Have a look at [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you store the number as a Decimal, it will output in non-scientific (normal) notation.  Depending on where the data is coming from, you may have to convert from double:

```
double myNumber = -0.0000094821028806535423;
Object CellData = new Decimal(myNumber);
```

(gives -0.00000948210288065354), or you may be able to directly use a Decimal:

```
Object CellData = -0.0000094821028806535423m;
```

The result is less precise if you convert from double as a double cannot exactly represent all numbers, and the more calculations you perform on them the further they may end up from an exact result.

If the number originates in your code and you don't need to perform any calculations on it, you could also just store it as a string directly.

Comment: If you want to convert the number to string, then it doesn't make sense to convert it to `decimal`. Just use `ToString()` with the correct format parameter.

Comment: It may shave milliseconds off the execution time, but to me that code would be far more difficult to decipher. It seems difficult to get any of those parameters to output all digits without truncating or trailing zeros, and the result will still only have up to double precision, truncating 2 digits with the number in the question.

Comment: If you have a `double`, then converting it to a `decimal` may show with more digits of precision, but that doesn't mean the number is actually more accurate, it's not. And for me, converting to some other data type because of formatting would be difficult to decipher.

Comment: I looked into the formats,but none solves my problem. The moment we do toString() it will truncate zeros. That is our main issue. We must stop truncating leading or trailing zeros.

Answer (score -1):

Try without the

```
output = string.Format("{0}", CellData);
```

Leave only the

```
output = CellData.ToString();
```

Comment: The CellData.ToString() truncates zeros. I know we can get this by using formats, but I cannot get any format which stops truncating zeros.